# Angular stop Router NavigationStart

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is it possible to stop the NavigationStart in Angular? I'm trying to prompt a custom confirmation modal if the user tries to change the route.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    if(val instanceof NavigationStart){
        //prompt the confirmation modal and stop NavigationStart or at least 
          make it wait until user performs any action
    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: I was able to resolve this using canDeactive

Comment: @AkashAgrawal awesome, have adjusted answer, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent a route was resolving with the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) or [CanDeactive](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) class

Comment: CanActivate or CanDeactivate? I want to detect a route change.

Comment: Your answer doesnt provide a concrete solution to the issue, just a hint